# label problems in XCODE

Tags: objective-c, ios7

I have a label that needs to be shown when there is no rows in a table view - easy thats done! 
the problem is that I have used the hidden tick box in interface builder but the label still shows when you first run the application. I am using Testflight to get the simulation of downloading the app from the app store.

any ideas ? Even when I have put the following code in the viewdidLoad

```
[self.label.hidden = YES];
```

thanks

Comment: If there is no cell on tableView, then where you are subView the label

Comment: This has nothing to do with the `xcode IDE` The code should be either `self.label.hidden = YES;` (Not in `[ ]`) or `[[self label] setHidden:YES];` or `[self.label setHidden:YES];`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [self.label setHidden:YES]; in `-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews`

Comment: No that didnt work.. I would have thought if i disabled the label , it wouldnt come back on till i said hidden = NO;

Answer (score 0):

do your "self.label.hidden = YES" in your "`cellForRowAtIndexPath:`"  method, changing the "`self`" bit to "`cell`" (or whatever you designate your table view cell to be, if the label is in the cell).

Also, make certain you are correctly returning the right number of rows (e.g. ZERO) from your "`numberOfRowsInSection:`" data source method, if there's no data to be displayed in the table.

Answer (score 0):

In the method 'viewdidLoad' the label will be nil, because it is not load yet.

The cellForRowAtIndexPath method loads the label in memory of the device. To get a grip of the cell you must:

1. Define a custom cell layout (neatest)
2. Link the UILabel to the custom cell layout
3. Then in the cellForRowAtIndexPath you can use:

   [cell.labelName setHidden: YES]